# Leaflet event onclick zoom in and out (JavaScript)

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I just want to make onclick event in zoom in and zoom out. How can I do it?
I just confused to make it because zoom in and zoom out is something that generated by library.

Should I make new function?
How I make it possible?

Comment: look at this example http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/f9a75b1dc017e7a8af2a

Comment: it has to make another zoom button right? i just want to make some event when zoom in or zoom out clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your map variable is called *map*, this zooms in when you click the map:

```
map.on('click', function() {

   map.zoomIn();

});
```

If you're asking to fire an event when zooming happens, then use:

```
map.on('zoom', function() {

   alert('Zoom, zoom, zoom, zoom, I want you in my room');

});
```

You can also use the *zoomend* or *zoomend* events.

Comment: Amazing alert!!haha

Comment: thank you!! it works

Comment: Answer's doc URL is no loger valid. This seems to work better as of today: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-event

Answer (score 0):

Use [map events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-event). `zoomstart`,`zoom`,`zoomend` can be used. e.g.

```
map.on({zoom : yourfunction})
```

Comment: thank you it works!!